# Why is the size of this structure 16 Byte?

Tags: c, bitmap, size, padding

The size of `BITMAPFILEHEADER` should be 14 bytes, but when I run the code I get 16 bytes. I thought, it was because of padding so I added the `__attribute__((packed))`, but I still get 16 bytes. Why?

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;


typedef struct
{
WORD bfType;
WORD bfReserved1;
WORD bfReserved2;
DWORD bfSize;
DWORD bfOffBits;
} __attribute__((packed))
BITMAPFILEHEADER;

int main(void){

printf(" %i \n",sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
return 0;


}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  What options?

Comment: I'm correctly getting 14 bytes printed. As chux said, please provide some more info about your compiler.

Comment: The size should be 14 bytes, i don't think sizeof is accurate here. Try to use a char pointer and see exactly what the size is.

Comment: I suspect the padding now exist at the end.  Perhaps the `__attribute__((packed))` only handled inter-member padding?

Comment: I am using codeblocks .

Comment: Better to use `"%zu"` than `"%i"` with `sizeof` to avoid UB, yet I think some other issue exist.

Comment: @chux I tried to add the __attribute__((packed))  to every element in the structure still the same .

Comment: @Alessandro where did you compile ?

Comment: Although you will certainly get an answer, consider an alternative to the higher level coding goal and form a solution that does not require compiler extensions like `__attribute__((packed))`.  `BITMAPFILEHEADER` is commonly a padding problem.

Comment: code::blocks is an IDE, not a compiler.  It supports many different compilers, and it potentially matters which one you're using.

Comment: Your program compiles cleanly for me with GCC 4.8.5, and when the result is run, it prints "14".  This is what I would expect from GCC, based on its documentation of `__attribute__((packed))`.  Note that the whole attribute system is a GCC invention, not a provision of the standard.  If other compilers support it, then it is not certain that they provide the same semantics.

Comment: The compiler is GNU GCC .

Comment: @Maherkassem What version, and how **exactly** is it being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug was reported on the same problem in GCC 4.8.1.

[**attribute**((**packed**)) does not pack struct containing uint16_t with uint32_t](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61813)

A comment on the bug report states that:

> (**attribute**((packed)) doesn't work on mingw32 targets since ms-bitfields became the default).